# Youtube: how can you obtain the list of users which like or comment on a video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Using the Youtube API how can I obtain the list of user IDs/handels who commented or liked a youtube video?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here you can read about how to get the comments with YouTube API v2 (v3 does not support this yet): https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments#faq.

I don't think you can get the people who've rated the video.

Comment: In this api response will it give the username of the commenter?

Comment: "Each comment has an author, a title and content." Straight from the website in the answer. Please read it.